# Delete Tag `indian-movies` because `bollywood` tag is enough for the purpose

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

`indian-movies` tag has only two question , each of them have `Bollywood` tag too.
So there is no significance of having two tag for same meaning. Bollywood is only refers to Indian cinema in whole so there is no need for `indian-movies` tag.

Comment: Now, see this: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/548/indian-movies-and-bollywood-should-not-be-tag-synonyms

Comment: The site is growing, so wait until you see all the movies from different languages. Bollywood!=Indian movies at all!

Answer (score 4):

## Done.

Answer (score 4):

I don't agree with that..because India is a vast cinema producing country in various languages i.e Bollywood, Kollywood, Tollywood and so on.

I hope in future more people will ask question from different part of India, So definitely  would be needed a common tag to group all Indian movies.

Comment: but in todays date there is no kollywood,tollywood specific question and for bollywood questions there is no need to specify it as indian movie because whole world know that bollwood=india

Comment: @AnkitSharma Today, we have Questions on Kollywood. This is a new site, it takes time to grow, soon we will have questions even of Tollywood, Bhojpuri and all, What's the hurry with you?