# indian-movies and bollywood should not be Tag Synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

**bollywood** means movies made in the Bollywood Industry which generally consists of Movies in the language of Hindi, Hindi and English Mixed together, and very rarely completely English Movies.

indian-movies is not only about Bollywood but also about Kollywood which consists of Movies in the language of Tamil.

Hence, indian-movies and bollywood should not be Tag Synonyms.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/472/delete-tag-indian-movies-because-bollywood-tag-is-enough-for-the-purpose

Comment: @iandotkelly So they were separate before, making them one was a mistake, we must separate them again. Just as Vijin Paulraj has said.

Comment: To be fair on the moderators here, this question needs to be addressed by all people interested in indian movies here.  If you look at that other question, the proposal to drop indian-movies has 3 upvotes, compared to 1 vote for the objection from Vijin.

Comment: @iandotkelly Okay.

Comment: i never said to merge bollywood with indian-movies but i said to delete indian-movies tags that time because that time all bollywood movie have two tags(indian-movies and bollywood) but there is no need to specify indian-movies tag for a bollywood movie because everybody knows that its indian movie but for tollywood,kollywood etc, indian-movies tag should be there too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would like to raise a few other points in this regard

- I agree that Bollywood actually means a lot many different things, some of the movies like [Slumdog Millionaire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1010048/) or predominantly song and dance based, culturally India related, non Hindi speaking movies may be perceived as Bollywood, so users would have better chance of finding responses or posting questions in regards to those movies with Bollywood tag.
- If I am looking for anything particular for a non international Indian movie made in Hindi, my first gut feeling would be looking for the tag Hindi or Hindi-movies.
- Thus for kollywood, tollywood etc should just be represented by their language as Telugu, Kannada, Tamil, Bengali representative of questions for the regional movies and being synonymous of indian-movies or indian-cinema tags. 
  Thus voting in favor of separating bollywood tag from indian-cinema.

Answer (score 9):

I am sympathetic to myselfpoddar here, as it seemed odd to me to conflate bollywood and indian movies - but to be fair it is common to conflate hollywood and american movies.

This question, and the [near duplicates of it](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/472/delete-tag-indian-movies-because-bollywood-tag-is-enough-for-the-purpose), raises two issues which I would like the community to address.

1. What is the purpose of 'bollywood' regional tags in the first place?  On this site you do not get questions about American movie also tagged 'hollywood', or British movies tagged 'british'.  [This question here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/is-geeta-shown-as-a-trans-gender-in-the-tamil-movie-kanchana), was originally only tagged bollywood & kollywood, yet was not even tagged with the movie name - which is contary to how most other questions on this site are tagged.  Personally I think that these regional tags should mostly be used to ask questions about indian movies in general, not as an additional tag for questions about a specific movie.
2. What would the members of the community here who are interested in indian movies like to do with [indian-movies], [bollywood], [kollywood] tags?  It is common in everyday life to conflate the meaning of [hollywood] and [american-movies], but the moderators here would welcome some agreement from the community as to what to do with these indian tags.  We have two conflicting viewpoints which need agreement.

Comment: I did not tag the question with the movie name, just because I did not think that many questions will be asked on the particular movie - the tag would have just 1 question till the end of the world. Also, a tag for each question ever asked on the site would lead to really a large amount of tags - do we need that?

Comment: @myselfpoddar - the same could be said of many movie tags.  I was personally against individual movie tags, but the decision was made early on to tag all movie specific questions like that.

Comment: @myselfpoddar - personally, I think an indian-movie tag (or tags) would be helpful on a site dominated by western movies.

Comment: @iandotkelly as i know American movies and Hollywood movies are same, correct me if i am wrong. But Bollywood is a part of indian movies which also have some more movie industries too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, well that's the point, they are not strictly the same, but they are often used like that. The point of this meta post, was to allow people to vote to keep regional distinctions if they are considered important to people that follow Indian movies. I actually don't have any opinion on that, because I don't know much about the subject.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion Bollywood is a part of **indian-movies**, so I think **indian-movies** should be a master tag and **bollywood** should be its synonym. Similarly **Kollywood** should be synonym of **indian-movies**.

At current  **indian-movies** is a synonym of **bollywood** which is wrong and should be reversed. But Community discussion is needed for it. Not only Bollywood, there are Tollywood,  Sandalwood in India. There are so many regional languages, so there are so many movie industries.

Comment: +1 Tollywood, Kollywood, Sandalwood, Bollywood => synonyms of indian-movies.

Comment: @Mani sandalwood?? :-)

Comment: @KK. I think he is just giving fake example.

Comment: @AnkitSharma lets hope so.. :-) ;-)

Comment: [Sandalwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_of_Karnataka)

Comment: @Mani ohh.... didn't know about that.