# Indian-movies tag should not be a Synonyms of bollywood tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Few moths ago i raised a [Meta request](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/472/delete-tag-indian-movies-because-bollywood-tag-is-enough-for-the-purpose),to delete the [indian-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-movies) because its not feeling important that time. Every question that time consist of [indian-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-movies) tag and [bollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bollywood) tag regarding bollywood film questions. But my request got misinterpreted and  [indian-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-movies) tag made synonym of  [bollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bollywood) tag. Which is inappropriate. Bollywood is part of Indian movies. Indian film industry consist of many regional film industries like Tollywood etc. too.

So in my opinion [indian-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-movies) should be a head tag and  [bollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bollywood) as its synonym . Even [tollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tollywood) should be the synonym of [indian-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-movies) too. So by clicking on [bollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bollywood) tag we will not get [tollywoo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tollywoo) question which are not related but when we click on [indian-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-movies) tag we will get all result of Bollywood,tollywood etc.

They can be kept separate too but making [indian-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-movies) synonmym of [bollywood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bollywood) is wrong.

It may sound similar to [indian-movies and bollywood should not be Tag Synonyms](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/548/indian-movies-and-bollywood-should-not-be-tag-synonyms/549#comment1591_549).

Comment: I'm half tempted to get rid of all the *wood tags to begin with.  I don't see much purpose unless a question is directly asking about practices in that market.

Comment: @TylerShads Still Bollywood is is part of Indian movies market which is bigger the Bollywood. Consisting of various regional movie industries.

Answer (score 5):

### Disclaimer: No movie fan. No movie information, except a few movies.

The tag for Indian movies is a kind of information for non-Indians regarding the the content of a question involving an Indian movie. On the other hand, information regarding a movie's actual place in Indian cinema with regards to its place of origin and language requires separate tags, not only for foreigners but for Indians too. For example, I am a north Indian and I cannot possibly differentiate between Telugu or Tamil movies, and ditto for Bengali/Odissi movies. I am sure people from other parts of the nation would have problems differentiating Punjabi and Harayanvi movies.

I think what Ankit wants to say is that all Bollywood, Tollywood, Bhojpuri, Punjabi etc. industries are a part of what we might refer to as Indian Movies, but not the other way around.

For example, [Carry on Jatta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_On_Jatta) is a Punjabi movie, and any question involving it can be tagged under Punjabi and Indian-Movies. But since it is not a Bollywood movie, a question involving it should not be tagged under Bollywood.

Comment: +1, Nice answer with n example